# how to add ApiFuture interface to android project with gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I want to use ApiFuture interface from com.google.api.core package, but I don't know how to import it in my android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Gradle, add the following lines to your `build.gradle` file of android project:

```
 repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
  }
```

for more understanding you check [Google reference doc for setup](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup)

Comment: @user8549135, Thanks you can upvote it as well for more help.

Comment: I add this dependency but I still cannot add ApiFuture interface

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: can  you check link mention in link and https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=api-common&g=com.google.api&v=1.1.0&downloadable=1 for download jar

Comment: or you can download from https://github.com/googleapis/api-common-java and add it as library.

Comment: in which folder I should paste this files

Comment: you have to add as library in android studio file menu option.

Comment: can you check  Google reference doc for setup

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same error while using the code for firestore for my android app from [this site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). The problem was I chose the Java option instead of Android. ApiFuture is used for java (its part of the server SDK) so its not there in android . Please click the android tab and use that code.[Code for android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX9bF.png)

Comment: Hey, can you please type up the code instead of just linking to it? And definately don't screenshot

Comment: Hey I'm really sorry, I'm new here. I'll definitely keep this in mind in the future. Really sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Use Android Code & get rid of **ApiFuture**:

```
batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
    // ...
}
});
```

ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#java_4

Answer (score 0):

add this library in your gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
```

please make sure you are in Java Android rather then java tab in fireStore Doc
then you not require this library

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
implementation 'com.google.api:api-common:2.2.1'
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question, and where one would put that line of code.